# Поиск пропусков в последовательности чисел

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении думать, при вычислении пропуска в массиве:

> К567, К568, К569, К571, К572

Comment: Буква К если что кириллица

Comment: В заголовке "числа", а в вопросе не числа. Вам нужен алгоритм для этой конкретной последовательности или могут быть другого типа/вида?

Comment: Блин извиняюсь, мой косяк... Ну это пример данных которые точно есть, убрать в начале букву не проблема, просто не могу понять как узнать что мне не хватает цифр в последовательности

Comment: какой массив должен быть в конечном результате? или какой результат вам нужен?

Comment: @YurikGagarin, попарно сравниваете соседние числа последовательности, там где разница будет отличаться - там пропуск. Справедливо это для арифмитической последовательности, в противном случае нужны более сложные алгоритмы проверок.

Comment: @br3t я вот подумал про этот способ но подумал что сильно будет нагружать систему при больших проверках, ну раз ничего больше не поделать будем делать так, спасибо

Comment: @Arendach должен сказать что К570 не хватает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем немного подумав я все таки добрался до желаемого результата

```
while ($order_id_check_assoc = $order_id_check -> fetch_assoc()) {

    if (!isset($id_action)) {
        $id_action=$order_id_check_assoc['id_action'];
    }else{
        $id_action_num=substr($id_action, 2);
        $id_action_num++;
        $id_action=substr($id_action, 0,2).sprintf("%03d",$id_action_num);
    }

    if ($order_id_check_assoc['id_action']!=$id_action) {
        for ($i=substr($id_action, 2); $i < substr($order_id_check_assoc['id_action'], 2); $i++) { 
            echo '<br>Нет ID '.$id_action.'<br>';
            $id_action_num=substr($id_action, 2);
            $id_action_num++;
            $id_action=substr($id_action, 0,2).sprintf("%03d",$id_action_num);
        }
    }

}
```

Если есть предложения по улучшению пишите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен. Спасибо

Comment: Перед циклом запрос в базу данных с уже предусмотренной сортировкой по порядку

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я вас верно понял и это то чтовам нужно:

```
<?php

// массив с пропущенными значениями
$data = ['К1', 'К2', 'К4', 'С1', 'С3', 'С4', 'С7'];

$temp = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    preg_match('/([А-я])([0-9]+)/u', $item, $matches);
    list($full, $letter, $number) = $matches;
    $temp[$letter][] = $number;
}

$temp2 = [];
foreach ($temp as $letter => $item) {
    // извлекаем первый елемент массива и приводим его к числу
    $start = str_replace($letter, "", current($item));

    // извлекаем последний елемент массива и приводим его к числу
    $finish = str_replace($letter, "", end($item));

    // в цикле проходимся от наименьшего до наибольшено значения
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $finish; $i++) $temp2[] = $letter . $i;

}

// сортируем по значению в порядку возростания
sort($item);

print_r($temp2); // ['К1', 'К2', 'K3', 'К4', 'С1', 'C2' 'С3', 'С4', 'C5', 'C6' 'С7']
```

Comment: Да в принципе все верно, но в твоем случае буква теряется, а это не хорошо так как буквы могут быть другие. Да я понимаю что это было не оговорено, но это и не претензия, спасибо большое

Comment: то есть могут быть 2 массивы с разными буквами `['k1','k2'...,'k10'],['g1','g2'...,'g10']` или `['k1','p2',...'s10']` ??

Comment: Массив один а в нем разные буквы

Comment: ну ок, хорошо припустим у на есть такой массив `['k1','p2', ???, 's4']` вместо ??? должна стоять какая-то буква и тройка(3) но какая именно буква??? и почему??

Comment: нет, мы ищем в последовательности К и С отдельно, они уникальные, т.е. К1, К2, К4, С1, С2, С3, С5 получается что пропущено К3 и С4

Comment: с этого надо и начинать

Comment: Прости, не всегда могу четко и ясно рассказать всю ситуацию

Comment: подправил ответ